# Proxypass and proxypassreverse perhaps with RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, proxy, reverse-proxy

i have a question regarding proxypass and proxypass reverse.

I want to be able to reach the following on my app (internally)

https://examplehost/**appname**/Servletname?method-to-call

But i want people who enter the website externally to see the following:

https://examplehost/Servletname?method-to-call

I have the following in my apache2 .conf file

> Proxypass `/ http://examplehost/appname/`
>
> ProxypassReverse `/ http://examplehost/`

However, when i call my own website externally i get the following error message:

> Request URL does not match Recipient URL, "/appname/Servletname?" does
>   not match "/Servletname?

This indicates that the external link not only has a matching problem, but it also sees the wrong link in the first place, since it shouldnt be possible for the external source to see "appname".

I also tried doing the following in the .conf file

> Proxypass `/ http://examplehost/appname/`
>
> ProxypassReverse `/ http://examplehost/appname/`

Does anyone know how to hide the **appname** without removing access to the app in the webapplication?

Thankful for any helpful answers or links.

Answer (score 1):

A simple internal `RewriteRule` should allow to rewrite this is a transparent manner. No need for a proxy strategy with its additional request round trip:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?Servletname$ /appname/Servletname [L,QSA,NC]
```

I don't really understand the error message you cite, but I have very little information. Question is which component gives that error message... server side? client side? servlet side?

When you require the usage of the proxy module (why ever...) then take a look at the `P` flag provided by apache's rewrite module. Alternatively using `ProxyPass` directives certainly should be possible too, I only don't see any reason for that. Nevertheless I would suggest something like this:

```
ProxyPass /Servletname https://examplehost/appname/Servletname
ProxyPassReverse /Servletname https://examplehost/appname/Servletname
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using .htaccess style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: We have a need for a proxy strategy for other reasons, right now im just trying to make the application work aswell, hehe. thank you for your answer sir. I will try it right away

Comment: @MarcusH Ok, can't say anything about that, again because of a lack of information.

Comment: security nightmare in what way? that the web application itself fails to show data or that people can access the wrong things?

Comment: @MarcusH Security always means that access is granted to things that should _not_ be reachable. An application merely not working as expecting is not a security issue. Imagine a flaw in the apps code that allows an attacker to smuggle in code that is written into the `.htaccess` file? ... For security reasons such code should _never_ be writable by the http server itself, so by an app served by that server. But as said: that is for the usage of `.htaccess` style files as you hinted in your tags. Your text implies that you do not actually do that.

Comment: Ok sir, I will forward this! Thank you

Comment: I'm still having some typo in the conf file btw, ill make sure to update you when ive managed to try this rewriterule, hehe.

Comment: Okey now i tried to do the following, first i removed everything in the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse so it was only an IP, like following / http://examplehost/ 

I also added the line above with the RewriteRule, (tomcat starting page) was the result of this

Comment: Should i use both (proxypass, proxypassreverse) and the rewriterule at the same time? or am i doing this wrong?

Comment: You either internally rewrite or you setup a proxy. Not both.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your great knowledge sir, we are now using a rewriterule instead of a proxy strategy, part of the problem still remains unsolved but the path problem is now fixed.